# Javascript function after uncheck all

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a function which clears all checkbox values and then make an AJAX request, but sometimes it fires before the checkboxes are unchecked.

```
function clear() {
  $("#a").prop("checked", false);
  $("#b").prop("checked", false);
  $("#c").prop("checked", false);
  ajaxFunction();
}
```

Is there any alternative without using a timeout? Using Promise for example, or something else?

Comment: Please share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: when do u call the clear function?

Comment: `but sometimes it fire before unchecked.` This is not possible as `prop()` is a synchronous operation. The issue, if there is one, is likely caused by an unexpected logic flow. Please add a more complete sample of your HTML and JS.

Comment: It doesn't fire before the checkboxes are unchecked.  It may appear to do that if the display has not been updated, but the code does run in the order that you have it.  If you're bothered by it, just change the last line to `setTimeout(ajaxFunction, 100);` (notice no brackets after `ajaxFunction`)

Comment: Promises are generally for asynchronous code, as `.prop` is synchronous, you would not get a benefit from use a promise here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
function uncheckAll(txtID) {
    $('#' + txtID + ' :checkbox:enabled').prop('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})